# Finding volume of enclosed region

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, volume, area

The base of `S` is the region enclosed by the parabola $y = 9 − 9x^2$ and the X - axis. Cross-sections perpendicular to the X - axis are isosceles triangles with height equal to the base.

Comment: Can you find the area of cross-section "at" $x$?

Comment: Side length of isosceles triangle is sqrt(5x^2) and 2x with base of 2x, so area is x^3

Comment: The base is $9-9x^2$, the height is the same, so the area of cross-section is what? Now what do you do to find the volume?

Comment: then it is (9-9x^2)*(9-9x^2)/2 since base and height are the same and we are trying to find the area of the triangle

Comment: Now what do you do to find the volume of the solid?

Answer (score 2):

You want to take the volume as
$$V=\int_a^bA(x)\, dx,$$

where $A(x)$ is a typical area slice. I think from comments you can see that
$$A(x)=\frac{1}{2}BH,$$

where $B$ is the base of the triangle and $H$ is the height. Thus
$$A(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(9-9x^2\right)\left(9-9x^2\right).$$

It helps to sketch these things to see what is going on. Learn how to sketch 3 dimensional solids and your life will be much more enjoyable. Next you want the limits of integration. They are the the zeroes of the function $y$, this being where the function meets the $x$ axis, and trivially found. See if
$$V=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}\left(9-9x^2\right)^2\, dx$$
meets with your mathematical sensibilities.